# angular $http gracefully handling errors

Tags: php, angularjs

Can someone give background on how $http works with respect to JSON, is it detecting the format of output and converting it to JSON automatically on success or do I've to handle this manually?

If that's the default behavior what happens if it can't convert the output to JSON?

Context: In this case where my web service failed because of sql connection error but `success` still got called

My $http related code sequence:

```
    this.$http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";

    this.$http.get(common.Config.getEndPoint() + "/sync", {params:params})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            self.onResult(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(data)
        });
```

**Error** - (because my mySQL server wasn't running, this can be fixed but my objective is to gracefully handle this error on the frontend if this happens, **looking for a good strategy both on the backend as well as frontend**)

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
```

PHP line that generated the error

```
$statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM `user` WHERE username = :username AND suspended = 0 AND deleted = 0");
```

Learning:
success gets run for any 2xx status codes, while error runs for any 1xx, 3xx, 4xx & 5xx

Comment: Is the server setting the `Content-Type` header when it responds to the request? If not, then you have to tell `$http` what to expect.

Comment: What status code is returned from the web service?

Comment: @NeilSmith I've edited the code to address your question, the point is to how to gracefully handle this situation?

Comment: @user2727195 please change question subject. It doesn't refer to your problem

Comment: I asked because the api is returning something like a 200OK even though the DB is down. IMO, you should return a 50x code instead so that your error callback is executed instead of the success callback. You can handle this on the frontend by checking the status code is actually successful in your success callback. But that's not fixing the actual issue which is that your api is returning a success when it should actually return an error.

Comment: @Brett can we do something like `if ($this->connection)` but that just spits out the error output without letting me to specify a status code like 500

Comment: Why can't you set the status inside of an else for said if condition?

Comment: What the server responds with content-wise is irrelevant as long as you correctly set the status header. With a status header of 500, angular will run the error handler.

Comment: so let me recap - if server response is success (200) with content-type is JSON, the angular $http will automatically handle the parsing part, and call the success, but if some other status code, it will run the error handler? correct?

Comment: It will execute the success callback for any of the successful status codes and error for the others. It determines if the response was successful or not by the response's status code. See here http://httpstatus.es/

Comment: ok so in general `success` will run for any 2xx and `error` will run for any 5xx?

Comment: I believe `error` will run for 4xx also.

Comment: Ok, I just checked, error runs for 1xx, 3xx, 4xx, 5xx, while success only runs for 2xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a success status code is returned without valid JSON data. This is due to your API returning an incorrect status code. You should fix this in your API if you want to actually fix the problem:

```
if db is down
    return 503 or something.
```

Otherwise, you can check the status code in your success callback:

```
this.$http.get(common.Config.getEndPoint() + "/sync", {params:params})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (status starts with 2)
            self.onResult(data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data)
    });
```

But this isn't the proper fix imo. Your title is asking for a graceful way to handle errors and the 2nd approach isn't graceful.

Also note the pseudo code in there (I forget if status is a string or number).

Comment: can you please help me with caching, it's still stuck to old output, added cache param but no use, if I change params itself I get latest output. `this.$http.get(common.Config.getEndPoint() + "/sync", {params: params, cache: false})`

Comment: A second question really belongs in its own question to help future readers out. Link me to the question if you decide to make one and I'll check it out.

Comment: I'd but I'm afraid some idiots here are too eager to down vote before I actually get a chance to enhance a question after discussion, sometimes in certain domains I'm not clear what needed to be asked, any advice?